# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: received Inspector.detached event

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Intermittently I am getting this error though I have latest browser & chromedriver versions.

```
    startWebDriver();
    util.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    util.driver.navigate().to(url);
```

Its opening browser some times its showing this error before navigating to URL, sometimes after navigating to URL etc, its highly dynamic.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: received Inspector.detached event
(Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'MBP15-PBJGH8.local', ip: '2601:641:480:1b80:f8d0:dd9d:d22b:865a%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.5', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 76.0.3809.100, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 76.0.3809.126 (d80a294506b4..., userDataDir: /var/folders/mz/2_llwtkx31d...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:58968}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: f2cb32ece44a24c5b9423f9d86ac5503
```